# Index view returns nulls

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, erb

I have this in my controller:

```
class TeamsController < ApplicationController
  respond_to :json 
  def index
    @teams = Teams.all
    respond_with @teams 
  end
  def show
    @team = Teams.find params[:id]
    respond_with @team
  end
```

This is how my views look like:

```
<%= render partial: "team", object: @team %> #file-show.json.erb
[<%= render partial: "team", collection: @teams, spacer_template: "comma" %>] #file-index.json.erb
<%= @team.to_json.html_safe %> #file- _team.json.erb
```

but the response for teams.json is always [null, null, null] while the response for teams/1.json is correct {"id"...}
Any idea what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `_team.json.erb` partial you are using the variable `@team` which is only set up in your show action. If you use `team` instead it should work because the partial rendering process sets that to be either `@team` or each of `@teams` in the case of show and index respectively.

So, your partial should be :

```
<%= team.to_json.html_safe %>
```

Comment: but I am using collection of @team in the index.json.erb... shouldnt it pick it up automatically?

Comment: using team throws an error: undefined local variable or method `team'

Comment: The object you pass in will be put into the variable `team` rather than `@team`. Where are you getting an undefined local variable from?

Comment: from _team.json.erb when I try /teams.json